# Dealing with very long running rake task

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rake, delayed-job, rake-task

I am interested in running a very long running rake task, one that would take hours to complete and I am interested in learning about best practices for dealing with this problem.

Possible solutions I have found:

1. Set up a cron job
2. delayed_job
3. resque

cron seems like a simple solution to set up, but is it ideal for a very long task? What do you use and what are the advantages/disadvantages of your solution?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Personally I love Resque, you can use the resque-scheduler gem for dealing with long running or periodic tasks.

If you don't have to run your task very often, you can demonize the the rake task to make sure it keeps running if your SSH session dies or something.

Try something like this:

```
nohup rake my:task &
```

`nohup` will send the output to `nohup.out` in the directory you run the task in, and will also let leave your ssh session without the process dying, secondly the `&` will run it as a deamon.

Comment: This looks like it will meet my needs perfectly. I'm going to keep this question open for a bit of time before I accept to hear others pov. Thanks!

Comment: No prob! I hope you find the solution you're looking for! Post your solution once you find it!

Answer (score 1):

In one application I created, users had the ability to upload PDFs which were thumbnailed upon uploading to create the preview images.  As the PDFs could be extremely large, thumbnailing could take a while and had to run in the background.  To do this, I used

- [Paperclip](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip) for the uploading,
- the [delayed_paperclip](http://www.jstorimer.com/ruby/2010/01/30/delayed-paperclip.html) gem to hand off thumbnailing to a background process,
- [Resque](https://github.com/blog/542-introducing-resque), backed by [Redis](http://jimneath.org/2011/03/24/using-redis-with-ruby-on-rails.html), to handle the worker queue, and
- the [God](http://godrb.com/) gem, to launch the Redis and Resque workers and monitor the whole shebang.

On the plus side, you get the nifty Resque GUI to view your workers in action, and you've got God there to watch for (and kill, and restart) runaway processes (which tend to occur quite a bit when you're processing PDFs in ImageMagick), making the whole thing much more stable and reliable.

On the minus side, it's a heck of a lot harder to set up than a cron job.  But having cron run a long, memory-intensive process unmonitored seems like a recipe for disaster to me.

Hope that helps!